# How do you add Event Handlers to MapPolygons in WP8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, here-api

I've currently got a Windows Phone 8 application with a map where I am adding a MapPolygon to the map.

I would like to add an Event Handler to the MapPolygon so that I can 'Tap' the MapPolygon and it would navigate to another page.

However, there is not built in 'Gesture' handling for MapElements.

Here is what I've tried:

- Through NuGet I added the Windows Phone Toolkit package
- I tried to create a "GestureService" and apply a 'Tap' event/gesture to the MapPolygon

Here is what the code looks like:

```
var poly_gesture = GestureService.GetGestureListener(poly);
poly_gesture.Tap += new EventHandler<GestureEventArgs>(Poly_Tap);


private void Poly_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
    // Handle the event here.
}
```

The problem is that the Poly_Tap method never gets fired.
The 'GestureService' shows a warning that it is now 'obsolete' despite the fact that I have the Windows Phone Toolkit package installed. Is there a new/better/different way of creating a gesture/event handler for a MapElement?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I came up with:

```
// A method that gets called when a user clicks on a map.
    private void map1_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {

        // When a user clicks the map, turn this into a GPS location.
        var point = e.GetPosition(map1);
        var location = map1.ConvertViewportPointToGeoCoordinate(point);

        // Make variables to store the latitude and longitude.
        double smallest_lat = 0; 
        double largest_lat = 0;
        double smallest_long = 0;
        double largest_long = 0;

        // Loop through each coordinate of your Polygon
        foreach (GeoCoordinate gc in poly.Path)
        {
            // Store the values of the first GPS location
            //  into the variables created above
            if (smallest_lat == 0)
            {
                smallest_lat = gc.Latitude;
                largest_lat = gc.Latitude;
                smallest_long = gc.Longitude;
                largest_long = gc.Longitude;
            }

            // For each new GPS coordinate check to see if it is 
            //  smaller/larger than the previous one stored.
            if (gc.Latitude < smallest_lat) { smallest_lat = gc.Latitude; }
            if (gc.Latitude > largest_lat) { largest_lat = gc.Latitude; }
            if (gc.Longitude < smallest_long) { smallest_long = gc.Longitude; }
            if (gc.Longitude > largest_long) { largest_long = gc.Longitude; }

        }

        // Call the "isWithin" function to identify if where
        //  the user clicked is within the Polygon you're looking at. 
        btnPoly.Content = isWithin(location, smallest_lat, largest_lat, smallest_long, largest_long);

    }

    // A function that determines if a user clicks withing a specified rectangle
    public Boolean isWithin(GeoCoordinate clicked_gc, double smallest_lat, double largest_lat, double smallest_long, double largest_long)
    {

        bool slat = clicked_gc.Latitude >= smallest_lat;
        bool llat = clicked_gc.Latitude <= largest_lat;
        bool slong = clicked_gc.Longitude >= smallest_long;
        bool llong = clicked_gc.Longitude <= largest_long;

        // Returns 'true' if the user clicks in the defined coordinates
        // Returns 'false' if the user doesn't click in the defined coordinates
        return slat && llat && slong && llong;
    }
```

Comment: There is an API that does this for you: GetMapElementsAt(point). It will return all MapElements at the given location. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.maps.controls.map.getmapelementsat(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Thanks... that would have been a lot easier!